# XML to list and back to XML

Tags: r, xml

Situation: "Software" to R and back to "Software". The only interface for "Software" is xml.

In R, I need to make a few changes in the file so i convert it to a list and make some changes.

```
library(XML)
myFile = xmlParse("myXML")
xml_data <- xmlToList(myFile)
xml_data$timetable$train$.attrs[6] = "HelloNewWorld"
```

Now i need to convert this list "xml_data" it back to xml.

I found some functions like this:

```
function(item, tag) {
  # just a textnode, or empty node with attributes
  if(typeof(item) != 'list') {
    if (length(item) > 1) {
      xml <- xmlNode(tag)
      for (name in names(item)) {
        xmlAttrs(xml)[[name]] <- item[[name]]
      }
      return(xml)
    } else {
      return(xmlNode(tag, item))
    }
  }

  # create the node
  if (identical(names(item), c("text", ".attrs"))) {
    # special case a node with text and attributes
    xml <- xmlNode(tag, item[['text']])
  } else {
    # node with child nodes
    xml <- xmlNode(tag)
    for(i in 1:length(item)) {
      if (names(item)[i] != ".attrs") {
        xml <- append.xmlNode(xml, listToXml(item[[i]], names(item)[i]))
      }
    }    
  }

  # add attributes to node
  attrs <- item[['.attrs']]
  for (name in names(attrs)) {
    xmlAttrs(xml)[[name]] <- attrs[[name]]
  }
  return(xml)
}
```

But this doesnt work...

Any help or hints appreciated!

Thanks!

In the linked picture you can see the current xml-file. Highlighted in yellow the values that I need to change.

Link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/remzj.png

Comment: It might help to see XML, current and desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. No need to rewrite the entire tree in R. Using its [xslt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xslt/index.html) package (available on CRAN-R), extension of `xml2`, you can transform an input source and write output to screen or file.

Using the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) to copy document as is, below XSLT then rewrites one of the attributes in `<train>` tag, `@source`, similar to your above code attempt but with sixth attribute.

**XML** *(sample input from [railIML Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RailML))*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<railml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="timetable.xsd">
    <timetable version="1.1">
        <train trainID="RX 100.2" type="planned" source="opentrack">
            <timetableentries>
                <entry posID="ZU" departure="06:08:00" type="begin"/>
                <entry posID="ZWI" departure="06:10:30" type="pass"/>
                <entry posID="ZOER" arrival="06:16:00" departure="06:17:00" minStopTime="9" type="stop"/>
                <entry posID="WS" departure="06:21:00" type="pass"/>
                <entry posID="DUE" departure="06:23:00" type="pass"/>
                <entry posID="SCW" departure="06:27:00" type="pass"/>
                <entry posID="NAE" departure="06:29:00" type="pass"/>
                <entry posID="UST" arrival="06:34:30" type="stop"/>
            </timetableentries>
        </train>
    </timetable>
</railml>
```

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, rewrites the @source attribute)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@source">
        <xsl:attribute name="source">HelloNewWorld</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**R**

```
library(xslt)

doc <- read_xml("/path/to/Input.xml", package = "xslt")
style <- read_xml("/path/to/XLSTScript.xsl", package = "xslt")
new_xml <- xml_xslt(doc, style)

# OUTPUT TO SCREEN
cat(as.character(new_xml))

# OUTPUT TO FILE
write_xml(new_xml, "/path/to/Output.xml")
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<railml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="timetable.xsd">
  <timetable version="1.1">
    <train trainID="RX 100.2" type="planned" source="HelloNewWorld">
      <timetableentries>
        <entry posID="ZU" departure="06:08:00" type="begin"/>
        <entry posID="ZWI" departure="06:10:30" type="pass"/>
        <entry posID="ZOER" arrival="06:16:00" departure="06:17:00" minStopTime="9" type="stop"/>
        <entry posID="WS" departure="06:21:00" type="pass"/>
        <entry posID="DUE" departure="06:23:00" type="pass"/>
        <entry posID="SCW" departure="06:27:00" type="pass"/>
        <entry posID="NAE" departure="06:29:00" type="pass"/>
        <entry posID="UST" arrival="06:34:30" type="stop"/>
      </timetableentries>
    </train>
  </timetable>
</railml>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is absolutely awesome!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. I hope you enjoy XSLT as much as I do.

Answer (score 0):

I found it hard to apply many of the answers listed here so I wonder if this set of simple Java XML XPathHelper Unities may help others. [You can find the source code here](https://github.com/AlexanderADELAU2/Java-XML-Helper-Utilities).   I didn't write it all myself but adapted code I found, so I can't take all the credit but it works and it is compact and hope it helps others.

```
    String xmlPayLoad = readFileAsString(payLoadPath + "/payLoad.xml");
    TreeMap<String, String> header = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    XPathHelperCommon xph = new XPathHelperCommon();
    header = xph.findMultipleXMLItems(xmlPayLoad, "//header/*");
    header.put("type", "newProcess");
    xmlPayLoad = xph.modifyMultipleXMLItems(xmlPayLoad, "//header/*", header);
```

The primative XML `header`  could be something like this:

```
<header>
  <type>process</type>
  <ruleBaseVersion>0</ruleBaseVersion>
  <ruleBaseCommitment>0</ruleBaseCommitment>
  <sequenceId>0</sequenceId>
  <priortiseSID>0</priortiseSID>
  <monitorIncomingEvents>0</monitorIncomingEvents>
  <activityCount>0</activityCount>
  <taskElapsedTime>0</taskElapsedTime>
  <processStartTime>0</processStartTime>
  <processElapsedTime>0</processElapsedTime>
  <eventElapsedTime>0</eventElapsedTime>
  <status>0</status>
</header>
```